# Unregister DNS-SD service on Windows.Networking.ServiceDiscovery.Dnssd API

Tags: c#, sockets, win-universal-app, service-discovery, dns-sd

I can register a DNS-SD service correctly but i'am not able to unregister a DNS-SD service from the local network . I've tried using `Dispose()` method to close the `StreamSocketListener`, but doesn't work .

Code of method to register the service is below. Anyone can help me remove the service from the local network

```
private async void RegisterService()
{          
    listener = new StreamSocketListener();
    await listener.BindServiceNameAsync("");
    listenServ = new DnssdServiceInstance("service._type._tcp.local", null, 211);

    try
    {
        var result = await listenServ.RegisterStreamSocketListenerAsync(listener);                  
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //error
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no need to put the tags in your question's title.